# CSS repeating sections. Need an image on the first instance

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have some repeating HTML which contains an image in it's headings.  I only need the first instance of the heading to have the image and I've been playing around with pseudo classes to no avail so far because i CAN'T reference the parent element.  Is there a way of saying very specifically to choose the first instance of the class name on the page regardless of it's parent?

**HTML**

```
<aside>
    <div id="JSreference1">
        <div class="asideHeader">
            <h2>HEADING 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="asideBody">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="JSreference2">
        <div class="asideHeader">
        <h2>HEADING 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="asideBody">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
.asideHeader{
    width: 248px;
    border: 1px solid #001D56;
    border-radius: 10px;    
    margin : 0 0 1% 0;
    background: #D5D5D5 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/syMZp/

Please see my JSFiddle for more clarity.  NOTE: please run the fiddle to see the image as it's referencing from the web.  I've split out the asideheader to distinguish between the b/g image and the heading itself.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: does :first-child not work?

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique. You cannot have two elements with an ID of "JSreference".

Comment: as the id isn't relevant for this example i just put a generic 'JSreference' in there.  I'm aware of IDs needing to be unique.  I'll add 1 and 2 next time! :)

Answer (score 1):

As James Donnelly said, IDs should be unique.

Use #JSreference .asideHeader selector to select the first one.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/syMZp/1/

```
#JSreference .asideHeader {
    background: #D5D5D5 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, fix your IDs, but that's not really relevant to your question. This does what you want:

```
aside div:first-child .asideHeader{
    background: #D5D5D5 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

...but you say you can't reference the parent element (perhaps because your DOM varies across the pages you want to use this on?)

In that case all I can think is to  resort to javascript, e.g.: `document.getElementsByClassName('asideHeader')[0].className="asideHeader newClassNameForThisNode"` (and put the header image on that new class name.)

(I do feel a little icky recommending a javascript fix for a CSS problem, but hey at least I didn't stuff jQuery down your throat...)

Comment: yeh, thanks, i want to steer away from JS but i'll plus one you for not being pedantic over the ID placeholder! :D

Answer (score 0):

To address your HTML as you've written it, you can use the nth-of-type selector to pick the first `JSreference` element, and then get its child header. Remember that nth-of-type must refer to elements that have the same parent, which is why you can't use it directly on the `.asideHeader` class. The `.asideHeader` elements don't share an immediate parent. However, the `#JSreference` elements DO share an immediate parent, the aside element. So you can use nth-of-type on the `#JSreference` elements to pick the first one, and then select the `.asideHeader` of that first `#JSreference`.

```
#JSreference:nth-of-type(1) .asideHeader {
    width: 248px;
    border: 1px solid #001D56;
    border-radius: 10px;    
    margin : 0 0 1% 0;
    background: #D5D5D5 url("../img/logo.png") no-repeat right top;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/syMZp/

That said, this is not great HTML, since your ID element should be unique. Switch `#JSreference` to a class.